# std::vector - error: cannot delete objects that are not pointers

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Maybe someone can help me understand the error.

I write this code:

```
class Text
{
private:
    struct paragraph
    {
        vector<string> lines;       
    };

    vector<shared_ptr<paragraph>> paragraphs; 
public:

    Text()
    {
        paragraphs.push_back(shared_ptr<paragraph>(new paragraph()));
    }
};

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Text> pText(nullptr);
    Text text();
    pText.reset(&text);
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run it
I got this error:

```
    1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\memory(1664): error C2541: 'delete' : cannot delete objects that are not pointers
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\memory(1431) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>::_Resetp<_Ux>(_Ux (__cdecl *))' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Text,
1>              _Ux=Text (void)
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\memory(1607) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>::shared_ptr<_Ux>(_Ux (__cdecl *))' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Text,
1>              _Ux=Text (void)
1>          ]
1>          c:\documents and settings\owner\שולחן העבודה\e\class.cpp(29) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>::reset<Text(void)>(_Ux (__cdecl *))' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Text,
1>              _Ux=Text (void)
1>          ]
```

What is meant "cannot delete objects that are not pointers"?
I'm not trying to delete any object.

Comment: Don't use shared_ptr like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `Text text();` does not do what you think it does.

It parses it as the declaration of a *function* named `text` which accepts no argument and returns a value of type `Text`.

This is the reason why your line `pText.reset(&text);` does not compile.

However, you really do **not** want that line to compile: you are associating a `shared_ptr` object to a value with automatic storage duration: when the `shared_ptr` will go out of scope, it will try to `delete` that object, resulting in **Undefined Behavior** (most likely a crash in this case).

Comment: This is just a mildly vexing parse, not the most vexing one.

Comment: @K-ballo: Uh, I thought the term MVP was used to denote situations where something that was meant to be an object declaration was parsed as a function declaration. I shall rephrase it. Thank you.

Comment: `Text text();` is a Text-book example of the Most Vexing Parse.

Comment: @DeadMG: Ok, so my belief was correct. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @DeadMG: Hardly, that's just a bogus attempt to invoke the default constructor. There is nothing parse related, nor nothing that could be done to disambiguate the parsed expression as its not ambiguous to start with. The text book example of the Most Vexing Parse, from the book that coined the term, is in the form of `TimeKeeper time_keeper(Timer())` which can be disambiguated rewriting it as `TimeKeeper time_keeper((Timer()))`.

Comment: so this code is also wrong:  auto_ptr<int> p;
int i = 7;
p.reset(&i); Because I learned from this example.

Comment: @user1544067: `auto_ptr` is deprecated in C++11. It is a cumbersome attempt to implement unique ownership in C++03, when move semantics did not exist yet, and it has a number of pitfalls you can easily find by googling it. C++11 has `unique_ptr`, which should be used instead of `auto_ptr`. But yes, using `reset()` that way is wrong as well, on any kind of smart pointer.

Comment: @Andy Prowl - I mean in this example also the auto_ptr associating to object in the stack

Comment: @user1544067: Yes. I answered that in the last part of my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the most vexing parse, your code contains a fundamental flaw:

**You must not assign a pointer to a stack-allocated object to a `shared_ptr`.**

This code will cause undefined behaviour which in practice means lots of pain:

```
shared_ptr<Text> pText(nullptr);
Text text;
pText.reset(&text);
```

`shared_ptr` will try to `delete &text` at the end of its lifetime.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore [We just say “boom”](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0361748/quotes?qt=qt0558771). ;-)

Comment: There's also no shared ownership involved, so there should be no shared_ptr in this code at all.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus I'm not going to discourage anyone from using managed pointers!

Comment: @AlexChamberlain You should discourage people from using pointers that model wrong ownership semantics. `unique_ptr<T>` is sufficient in most cases, including this one. `shared_ptr<T>` is a specialised tool.

Answer (score 0):

You `main` function should read.

```
int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Text> pText(new Text);
    return 0;
}
```

You had 2 problems. First, `Text text()` was being parsed as a function declaration. Second, you were passing the address of a stack variable to a `shared_ptr`, which will `delete` the object when the reference count reaches 0.

You should also consider whether you need to use a `shared_ptr`. Will you ever be sharing this pointer with any body else, or do you simply want to ensure it is destructed properly? You could consider `unique_ptr` in the latter case. Do you even need a pointer at all, could you just allocate the object on the stack?

Comment: Actually, no. This makes no sense, not even in connection with your comment below my answer. The `main` function *should* read: `Text text;`. That’s it. No pointers – managed or unmanaged – necessary.

Comment: Also you construct `shared_ptr` with `make_shared`, not like that.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus Agreed, you could call `make_shared`. However, there's nothing wrong with what I have written. In fact, Meyers uses it on pg 77 of Effective C++ (3rd Edition).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I've tried to clarify that position. I assumed that the example given was a cut down version, instead of the full code base.